# Use Css to get Tr border bottom over Td border left in a TABLE

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I've a problem with a table: http://jsfiddle.net/ex6ZR/252/

```
    .tr td{
       border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

    .td1{
       border-right: 3px solid blue;
    }
```

My goal is to get a bottom-border (along all the TR) overriding a Td Left border.

It works when td.bottom-border-width > td.left-border-width but not when a bottom border thiner (and it's what i'm searching)

I found many solutions using :before & a block, but it works only with absolute position (and i can't set it because i'm in a table).

My result:

[image: Current Result]

Result expected:

[image: Result expected]

EDIT : Jsfiddle was failed :x The good one is here now

EDIT 2 :

The problem has been solved, thanks to Jess Bart. I've updated the jsfiddle, and the result is great :

```
table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td{
            position: relative;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        td::after {
            border-right:1px solid orange;
            content:'';
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            right: -1;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

Comment: and you are obliged to use table ?

Comment: I have updated the Jsfiddle if you can see it. Use outline instead of border that should give you the desired result

Comment: @Temani yes i should :x ;  Eskinder, Jsfiddle was wrong :x sorry first time i'm posting in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        td{
            position: relative;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        td::after {
            border-right:1px solid orange;
            content:'';
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            right: -1;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) did you read the question ? 2) how can a CSS work without HTML ?

Comment: The css is the css to replace in the jsfiddle. Do YOU even read the question?

Comment: yes i read it :) and i see this `My goal is to get a bottom-border (along all the TR) overriding a Td Left border.` which is not the result of you code

Comment: and also this part `It works when td.bottom-border-width > td.left-border-width but not when a bottom border thiner (and it's what i'm searching)`

Comment: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/753435Capture.png
My result looks like the result expected, and I have tested with a thiner bottom border and it works well.

Comment: Calm down guys :) First i'm sorry, jsfiddle was wrong, but you understood my question. That's the most important. I'll try right now your solution. Thanks